# Error: Minified React error #299 Div "root" problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I build my react app and trying to upload in in an ftp server but i still getting this error .

What i need to do ?

Its something about

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
```

But i cant figure it out . Here is the complete error  :

```
react-dom.production.min.js:319 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #299; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=299 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at t.createRoot (react-dom.production.min.js:319:204)
    at index.js:8:14
    at index.js:23:1
    at index.js:23:1
```

And the website error when i enter **legacy.reactjs.org**

```
createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

Comment: Have anybody fixed this problem?

Comment: Hello, it was because i put some files inside another folder so for some reason it had compile errors that was not reporting . You must put the files in main folder if i remember correct .

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was from an external dependency of Google Tag Manager.